# Run entire Snakemake pipeline in a scratch space

Tags: snakemake

I'm wondering if it's possible to run the entire Snakemake pipeline in a scratch space? I understand that the `shadow` directive allows one to run rules in isolated directories, but is it possible to do that for entire pipeline without having to write shadow for every rule?

Let me know if I'm missing something.

Comment: One option could be to create a new directory in the scratch space, symlink in your input files and snakemake workflow, then execute snakemake from that directory.

Comment: Did you get this to work @Vivek Rai?

Comment: @AlBro I adopted Nextflow as primary tool.. and that made it easier.